# problems with checking for a directory in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, batch-file

I am writing a batch-processing script bash that needs to first check to see if a folder exists to know whether or not to run a certain python script that will create and populate the folder.  I have done similar things before that do fine with changing the directories and finding directories from a stored variable, but for some reason I am just missing something here.

Here is roughly how the script is working.

```
if [ -d "$net_output" ]
then
    echo "directory exists"
else
    echo "directory does not exist"
fi
```

when I run this script, I usually echo $net_output in the line before to see what it will evaluate to.  When the script runs I get my else block of code saying "Directory does not exist", but when I then copy and paste the $net_output directory path that is echoed before into the shell terminal, it changes directories just fine, proving that the directory does in fact exist.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell machine.

Thank you in advance for any help that someone can offer.  Let me know what additional information I can provide.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the expected value for `$net_output`? Is it possible that it's value is a relative path to a directory that you aren't in? The code itself seems fine so I'd check that value to make sure it's what you expect

Comment: Another possibility is that it's in fact a symbolic link to a directory, in which case `cd` will work, but `[ -d ... ]` will return false...

Comment: @twalberg: test must succeed for a valid symbolic link.  From the standard: `With the exception of the -h pathname and -L pathname primaries, if a pathname argument is a symbolic link, test shall evaluate the expression by resolving the symbolic link and using the file referenced by the link.`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ooops... yeah, my bad. It seems modern shells do work that way, and I didn't actually test. I seem to remember that hasn't always been the case for all shells, but I don't remember which OS/shell combination caused me grief over that point in the past...

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I just found the problem and it was incredibly stupid.  For some reason I was actually declaring $net_output with a $ symbol in the declaration like...
net_output="$dir/file"
I've been doing a lot of coding lately and the simple things are escaping me.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cases I've encountered when someone posts a problem like this are the following:

**1.** The variable contains literal quotes. Bash does not recursively parse quotes, it only parses the "outer" quotes given on the command line.

```
$ mkdir "/tmp/dir with spaces"
$ var='"/tmp/dir with spaces"'
$ echo "$var"
"/tmp/dir with spaces"
$ [ -d "/tmp/dir with spaces" ]; echo $?
0
$ [ -d "$var" ]; echo $?  # equivalent to [ -d '"/tmp/dir with spaces"' ]
1
```

**2.** The variable contains a relative path, and the current directory is not what you expected. Check that the value of `echo "$PWD"` outputs what you expected.

**3.** The variable was read from a file with dos line endings, CRLF (\r\n). Unix and unix-like systems use just LF (\n) for line endings. If that's the case, the path will contain a CR (\r) at the end. A CR at the end of a line will be "invisible" in a terminal. Check with `printf '%q\n' "$var"` while debugging the script. See [BashFAQ 52](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052) on how to get rid of them.